# Spring MVC with Eclipse Jetty integration 8 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, embedded-jetty

I'm using Spring mvc with IDE (Rad 8.5.5) with Jetty Integration version 8 to create a small web application. 
When I attempt to submit the request **http://localhost:9090/testJetty/index**, Jetty returns the following error message: **WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/testJetty/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'**.

Here is my code:

#### web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>testJetty</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

#### app-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="test"/>

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        <beans:property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

#### Controller:

```
package test;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class test {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index")
    public String index(Model model) {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

The following requirements can't be changed:
 1. Project compiled with Jdk 1.6 
 2. Spring version 4
 3. Javax-servlet-api-3.1.0

I don't figure out what is the problem. Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we do not see your project structure,so it may not be correct.

But I guess the reason is because your jsp files is under `WEB-INF`,you need to add the following code in your `spring` configuration file:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Also change your dispatcher from `/*` to `/` in `web.xml`

```
   <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: You're right! I forgot a piece of code of app-servlet.xml above. I edited my question.

Comment: I did it, but I think that I have to reach at least 15 reputations before.

Comment: you can.accept it or upvote it .you can have a try .thank you